# Delay between SemaphoreSlim.Release() and SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync()

Tags: c#, console, task, semaphore

I'm testing a method involving a SemaphoreSlim to notify when an event has occured. It works as intended, but I've noticed that if I use this within the first few seconds of my application starting there is a large delay between the release of the semaphore and the continuation of my code waiting for the semaphore.

main:

```
            var userIntentProvider = new UserIntentProvider();

            Console.WriteLine("started");

            
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("starting");
                //wait for an event to be added.
                userIntentProvider.GetNextUserIntentAsync().Wait();
            });


            while (true)
            {
                var input = Console.ReadLine();
                //add the event
                userIntentProvider.AddUserIntent("bar");
            }
```

class:

```
        public void AddUserIntent(string userIntent)
        {
            NewUserIntent?.Invoke(this, userIntent);
        }


        public async Task GetNextUserIntentAsync(CancellationToken token = new CancellationToken())
        {
            var sw = new Stopwatch();
            //create signal
            var signal = new SemaphoreSlim(0, 1);

            //create event handler
            EventHandler<string> eventHandler = null;
            eventHandler = (sender, e) =>
            {
                NewUserIntent -= eventHandler;
                
                
                signal.Release(); //THE SEMAPHORE IS RELEASED AND THE STOPWATCH STARTED
                sw.Start();
            };

            //wrap in try catch to force removal of event
            try
            {
                //subscribe
                NewUserIntent += eventHandler;

                // wait for signal 
                await signal.WaitAsync();//THE SEMAPHORE IS WAITED ON AND THE STOPWATCH STOPPED
                sw.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("done" + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            }
            finally
            {
                NewUserIntent -= eventHandler;
            }
        }
```

The Stopwatch measuring the time between the Release() and await WaitAsync() calls can be up to 1.5s. If I wait for a few seconds after starting the application and then trigger this mechanism the stopwatch reports 0ms have passed (more like I was expecting) what could be causing this delay?

Edit: This is running in a console app.

Comment: What happens if you change the await to `await signal.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);`? (Probably won't help, but just in case)

Comment: ConfigureAwait(false) is not helping.